# How to call servlet from java code?

Tags: java, json

Now I am forming the URL in the browser, and execute it via REST api like

```
localhost:9043/api/json?apiKey=699cccc3dcfb348fd369e083bcd7f2a4&Severity=all
```

and will get some JSON Object output.

Instead of working on browser, I need to give the URL in the java code itself and to get the json object output also in java code itself. I have searched but not found yet. Need some experts answer for my question.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html

Comment: Google GSON example consuming rest or similar, there's loads of documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

it's just an HTTP call like any other, so you call it like any other HTTP call from a Java application, and get the results from that call like that as well.
So look up HttpURLConnection and go from there.

Comment: This is half an answer.  The OP will still need to take the JSON and turn it into something they can work with, though.

Comment: @IanMcLaird of course, but that's out of scope of his question on how to call a servlet from Java code. For that he'd need to call a JSON parser and work with the result of that, another thing he can find with a quick Google call.